# Prove that: $f(x)=x \leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$

Tags: analysis, functions, inverse-function

Let f a defined function in $\Bbb R+$ such as: $$f(x)=\sqrt{x\arctan{x}}$$

Prove that $\qquad $ $f^{-1}(x)=f(x) \leftrightarrow f(x)=x$

As an attempt, I've proven that f is a bijective function from $\Bbb R+$ to $\Bbb R+$, and I've proceeded by some equivalences : $$f(x)=x$$ 
$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \; \; \,\leftrightarrow f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(x)$ 
$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \; \; \,\leftrightarrow \qquad \quad \; \;  x=f^{-1}(x)$
$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \; \; \,\leftrightarrow \qquad \;  f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

Is this true? Or is there any other method ?

Comment: What do you mean "such as the $\sqrt{x\arctan x}$"?  If $f = \sqrt{x\arctan x}$ then $f^{-1} (x) \ne f(x)$, so why the heck did you bring up $\sqrt{x\arctan x}$ in the firstplace?

Comment: This isn't true. if $f(x) = \frac 1x$ then $f^{-1}(x) = \frac 1x = f(x)$.  But $f(x) \ne x$.

Comment: this question makes no sense, if you say that `f(x)=x` then `f^-1(x)=x`, there is nothing to prove